# Как переписать цикл for на while и do-while в Java?

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы, for, while

Решал задачи по выведению фигур в консоль и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается переделать цикл `for` на цикл while и do-while. Хотя с виду они одинаковые, помогите понять что не так, и как, в целом, лучше понимать циклы и алгоритмические задачи.
Вот пример с for:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print("%");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

А вот пример с while:

```java
while (i < 7) {
    while (j < i + 1) {
        System.out.print("%");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i++;
}
```

По идее они должны выводить одинаковую фигуру, но в примере с while не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере с `while` нужно было инициализировать `j` внутри цикла, а также можно было бы использовать пост-инкременты внутри самого оператора `while`:

```java
int i = 0;
while (i++ < 7) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j++ < i) {
        System.out.print("%");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Для оператора `do-while` начальное значение изменится на 1, так как в таком случае тело обоих циклов будет выполняться как минимум один раз:

```java
i = 1;
do {
    int j = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print("%");
    } while (j++ < i);
    
    System.out.println();
    
} while (i++ < 7);
```

---

Также хотел бы обратить внимание на существование метода [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) начиная с JDK 11 (сентябрь 2018), с использованием которого код заметно упростится благодаря устранению вложенных циклов:

```java
i = 0;
while (i++ < 7) {
    System.out.println("%".repeat(i));
}
i = 0;
while (i < 7) {
    System.out.println("%".repeat(++i));
}
i = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("%".repeat(++i));
} while (i < 7);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ. То есть у меня не получалась фигура, потому что вложенный цикл не видел переменную j? Это связано с областью видимости, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Тогда почему, если вызвать итератор внутри тела do {}, то цикл будет отрабатывать по-другому?

Comment: У вас в вашем примере основная проблема была с инициализацией `j` -- вложенный цикл не имел смысла после своего первого окончания без сброса `j`.

Comment: _почему, если вызвать итератор внутри тела do {},_  Какой итератор?

Answer (score 1):

Забыты мелочи...

```
 int i = 0;
 while (i < 7) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < i + 1) {
        System.out.print("%");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i++;
}
```